# Eclipse Oxygen Java Decompiler plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have noticed that, for eclipse oxygen, it is not available a decompiling plugin
Some times ago I used "Eclipse Class Decompiler plugin" (https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/february/article8.php ) but this too does not work anymore...
Can you help me find an alternative for decompiling java sources on eclipse oxygen
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read the [security bulletin about the Eclipse Class Decompiler](https://eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170814_security_bulletin.php)! How about [Bytecode Outline](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/bytecode-outline)?

Comment: Bytecode Outline isn't a decompiler...

Comment: What is your use case? How about running a decompiler (e. g. [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/)) from the command line via an _External Tool configuration_?

Comment: I would like to press F3 button and enter in decompiled class like IntellijIdea...

Comment: you can use: https://ecd-plugin.github.io/ecd/

Answer (score -1):

Try this eclipse plugin update site:
http://cnfree.github.io/Eclipse-Class-Decompiler/update

Comment: As mentioned by howlger, this tool is full of adware. See https://eclipse.org/org/press-release/20170814_security_bulletin.php